# [Python]Taking max value of first,second,third etc.. row from randomly generated matrice and creating vector with those max values

Tags: python, matrix

```
for i in range(0,3):
    mat=10*random.rand(3,3)
    v=[1,2,3]
    a=[]
    a(i)=mat[i,:].max()
    v.insert(i,a(i))
    #or v.insert(i,mat[i,:].max())
```

As said in the article, what i am trying to do taking max value of first,second,third etc row from randomly generated matrix and creating vector with those max values

Error window says: "cant assign to function call"
but i could not figure out how to fix

What i exactly wanna do is doing what i did below with for loop

```
from numpy import *
def minmaxvectors(mat1):
x1=mat1[0,:].max();
x2=mat1[1,:].max();
x3=mat1[2,:].max();

n1=mat1[0,:].min();
n2=mat1[1,:].min();
n3=mat1[2,:].min();

x=array([[x1],[x2],[x3]])
n=array([[n1],[n2],[n3]])
print "Matrix : ", m1
print "Maxes: ", x,"\n", "Mins: ", n
return x,n;
```

Comment: You don't have legal python code here. `a(i)` calls a function called `a` with the argument `i`. If you are trying to assign to an index, you need `a[i]` (note the different brackets). Your indexing (`mat[i,:]`) looks R-esque and is not legal python. Also, you can't assign to `a[0]` if the 0th element of `a` does not exist

Comment: thank you,  use [] these for matrix, got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working off @inspectorG4dget, you should use brackets instead of parentheses for indexing. You should create the vector to store these maximum values outside of the loop. You are currently overwriting this list. What does `v` do? You are recreating it, but not storing results. I thought you just want the maximum for each row.

You want the maximum value of a set of randomly generated numbers, but you are constantly recreating these random numbers.

```
   size=3
   a=[]
   mat=10*random.rand(size,size)
   for i in range(size):
     a.insert(i, mat[i,:].max() )
```

You can also do this in numpy very efficiently:

```
    size=3
    mat=10*np.random.rand(size,size)
    a = np.max(mat, axis=1)
```

editted: You can do this completely with just three lines in numpy. You don't need to use a loop! `np.max()` has a second argument that allows you to take the maximum over a certain axis.

```
    size=3
    mat=10*np.random.rand(size,size)
    max_entry = np.max(mat, axis=1)
    min_entry = np.min(mat, axis=1) 
    print 'Matrix:', mat
    print 'Maxes:', max_entry, '\n', 'Mins: ', min_entry
    return max_entry, min_entry
```

Comment: So what i was trying to do like try to pass inside a wall. Thank you. Got the idea, first create matrix then fill it

Comment: Whoops, my edit was too slow. You can just use the second argument in the [np.max](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.max.html)